# get image from template post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I use a crowdfunding-plugin for wordpress called personal fundraiser which you can see [here](https://github.com/jkleinsc/Personal-Fundraiser-Plugin-for-WordPress). It uses one post-type called cause and another called campaign. The campaign posts uses the cause posts as a template. The reason why i ask here is that the plugin-developer answer questions every second month or so.

There are one shortcode which i want to change the content of. The first thing i want is to get the campaing-image. I probably need a code to get it from the asociated cause (the template). The second thing i want is to echo shortcodes in the `$list_content` you see below. How do i add shortcodes there? If i use  `$list_content .= '<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>'` i get php-error. The code i want to change looks like this:

```
`function pfund_campaign_list() {
global $wp_query;
wp_enqueue_style( 'pfund-user', pfund_determine_file_location('user','css'),
array(), PFUND_VERSION );
$post_query = array(
'post_type' => 'pfund_campaign',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['pfund_cause_id'] ) ) {
$post_query['meta_query'] = array(
array(
'key' => '_pfund_cause_id',
'value' => $wp_query->query_vars['pfund_cause_id']
)
);
}
$campaigns = get_posts($post_query);
$list_content = '<ul class="pfund-list">';
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
$list_content .= '<li>';
$list_content .= ' <h2>';
$list_content .= ' <a href="'.get_permalink($campaign->ID).'">'.$campaign->post_title.'</a></h2>';
$list_content .= '</li>';

}
$list_content .= '</ul>';
return $list_content;
}`
```

In another function to list the causes, this code is used to get the cause-image, but when i use it in the campaign_list nothing happens:

```
`$cause_img = get_post_meta($cause->ID, '_pfund_cause_image', true);
if ( $cause_img ) {
$list_content .= '<img class="pfund-image" width="100%" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $cause_img ).'"/>';
}`
```

You can see the whole .php-file [here](https://github.com/jkleinsc/Personal-Fundraiser-Plugin-for-WordPress/blob/master/includes/user.php)

Any help is very much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get a shortcode in your theme do this

```
$list_content .= do_shortcode($content);
```

then you can change in your $list_content, you cant echo in a predefined variable.

In-place of

```
$list_content .= '<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>'
```